# Netbeans Platform: InstalledFileLocator

Tags: java, netbeans, filesystems, maven-3, netbeans-platform

I added a resource for a module as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>nbm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <moduleType>eager</moduleType>
        <nbmResources>                     
            <nbmResource>
                <directory>${basedir}/resources</directory>
                <targetPath>resources</targetPath>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.db</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>*trace*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </nbmResource>
        </nbmResources> 
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The file shows in the Netbeans application at: `target/app name/app name/resources/card_manager.mv.db`. That looks fine.

Now I'm trying to get that file location as follows:

```
File db = InstalledFileLocator.getDefault().locate("card_manager.mv.db",
                    "module.codename.base", false);
```

But db is always null. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
File file = InstalledFileLocator.getDefault().locate("myfile", null, false);
if (file == null) 
{
   file = new File(Places.getUserDirectory() + File. separator + "myfile");
}
```

Or have you tried resources/card_manager.mv.db? I'm sure the application path (app name) and cluster name (second app name) is excluded from locate() but I believe you have to include resources/ path.

Comment: Will give it a try and report back.

Comment: Didn't work, but I know I can make it work changing the resource location, etc, but is not what I want. I need to use InstalledFileLocator as various modules might have their own version of this file and I need to locate it by codenamebase.

Comment: Even if the bounty expires, I would give a good answer bounty points.

Comment: Yes, but is not what I need. I know I can make it work changing the resource location, etc, but is not what I want. I need to use InstalledFileLocator as various modules might have their own version of this file and I need to locate it by codenamebase.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your pom so that the `card_manager.mv.db` is copied to the classes folder rather than the resources folder and fetch the file from your classloader.

Comment: I know I can make it work changing the resource location, etc, but is not what I want. I need to use InstalledFileLocator as various modules might have their own version of this file and I need to locate it by codenamebase.

Comment: Even if the bounty expires, I would give a good answer bounty points.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In Maven the module codename base includes the pom groupId. Once you built your app you can check the exact codename base by checking the .jar filenames in `application/target/appname/appname/modules` (note that .jar files use "-" instead of ".").

For example in my Ant-based app I used:

```
File f = InstalledFileLocator.getDefault().locate("modules/soundfont/JJazzLab-SoundFont.sf2, "org.jjazz.fluidsynthembeddedsynth", false);
```

When switching to Maven I had to prefix the module groupId "org.jjazzlab":

```
File f = InstalledFileLocator.getDefault().locate("modules/soundfont/JJazzLab-SoundFont.sf2, "org.jjazzlab.org.jjazz.fluidsynthembeddedsynth", false);
```

So for you it should be:

```
File db = InstalledFileLocator.getDefault().locate("resources/card_manager.mv.db", "groupId.module.codename.base", false);
```

If you need a complete example that works in a Maven module, see the loading of `SOUNDFONT_FILE` in https://github.com/jjazzboss/JJazzLab/blob/dev/app/FluidSynthEmbeddedSynth/src/main/java/org/jjazz/fluidsynthembeddedsynth/FluidSynthEmbeddedSynth.java